# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-getx

```
class SplashServices {
  UserPreferences userPreferences = UserPreferences();

  void isLogin() {
    userPreferences.getUser().then((value) {
      if (value.token!.isNotEmpty && value.token.toString() != 'null') {
        Timer(
            const Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.toNamed(RouteName.homeView));

      } else {
        Timer(
            const Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.toNamed(RouteName.loginView));

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Since I am facing the problem of using null check operator on a null value
So
Kindly provide an alternate method to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your "If" statement, first check "value" is null or not and then do other checks. Do this (if(value==null)) first

Answer (score 0):

Here is issue is you check "null"

```
class SplashServices {
  UserPreferences userPreferences = UserPreferences();

  void isLogin() {
    userPreferences.getUser().then((value) {
         // Change only the conditions below
      if (value != null && value.token != null) {
        Timer(
            const Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.toNamed(RouteName.homeView));

      } else {
        Timer(
            const Duration(seconds: 5), () => Get.toNamed(RouteName.loginView));

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks, Jemish, but it gives me a warning: The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'.